# infoWindow when map is click

Tags: google-maps

I just want a map that when the map is click an infoWindow appears but without a marker. Furthermore, inside the infoWindow (using reverse geocoding) the address of where the user click on the map is also displayed. I have researched and try to code it but when i click the map the infoWindow does not appear. Where could be the bug or is there another way of doing it?Any help would be appreciated. Here is the site site hosted the map;

http://urloritdidnthappen.appspot.com/186002

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that here

```
infoWindow.open(map);
```

`map` is undefined. That's because this line

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
```

sets `map` to be *local* to the `initialize()` function.

**Fix**: remove `var` from the line `var map =...` so that it assigns a value to the global variable.

Comment: @jbElmas2012: Perhaps you'd like to click the tick next to the answer then. That helps us both (and marks the question as answered, so no-one else wastes time on it).